# What weapons should I use to battle the Destroyer?

Tags: terraria-console

I have tried to kill the Destroyer a couple of times. The first time I built the arena it killed me and I went back to my spawn point. It followed me and killed all of my MPCs. I don't use guns very much because I have terrible aim. I have a adamintite sword and mythril armor. What different kinds of weapons should I use since these are not working for me?

Comment: @PrivatePansy i disagree that question is for a speedrun and specifically asks for quick to acquire weapons.

Comment: @Aequitas, what tells us OP is playing on console, here?

Comment: @Timelord64 comments below my answer

Comment: Also, vote to remain closed. The other question has different context, but asks for the same thing. Good answers should not just meet the specfic requirements of the OP, and as such, we should be having all answers that address this question in the one place. This still works as a guidepost. I would recommend any new answer simply be posted on the duplicate.

Comment: @Aequitas, the only reference I can see to non-computer is Sharanga.

Comment: Sharanga is on [tag:terraria-console] as well as [tag:terraria-mobile], and I see no other mention to distinguish between the two.

Comment: I play on console. Sorry I didn't say that earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly suggest the [Nimbus Rod](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Nimbus_Rod) it's insanely effective against The Destroyer (and other multi-segmented enemies).

You can acquire them by killing Angry Nimbus's which appear on the surface when it's raining.

After acquiring only one rod, you can summon two clouds and then drop the item for your friends so that they can summon two more clouds each.

Use any other preferred weapons to augment the damage from the clouds, but the clouds will be your main source of DPS. You can even get the crimson rod for another cloud (although it does less damage).

Comment: Would a Minishark be effective against the Destroyer as well? I have heard that it is a good weapon to use. I also have a star cannon. Would that be effective?

Comment: not particularly, but it's as decent a weapon to use as any with the clouds.

Comment: penetrating weapons like spears and flails are strong, so are many arrows

Comment: What kind of bow should I use? I already have a Sharanga.

Comment: sharanga is fine, it's quite a decent bow, also you should have mentioned that you were playing terraria-console not terraria as there are many differences. Just make sure to use a penetrating arrow such as holy arrow , or jester's arrows (unholy arrows too but they don't penetrate as much)

Comment: no actually I just looked at the sharanga, i'm not sure if you do get the special properties of arrows with that bow, use a molten fury instead they are easy to craft.

Comment: Should I use the Molten Furry on the Probes? Or should I use a sword?

Comment: The minigun or a sword would probably be better as they can be quite difficult to hit. Just make sure to stand near the clouds so they form a kind of protective wall